# Play can't connect to MySQL

Tags: mysql, playframework, playframework-2.4

I am having trouble making Play connect to my MySQL database. I updated the application.conf file to include the database connection info but I get the following error:

```
    CreationException: Unable to create injector, see the following errors:1) Error in custom provider, Configuration error: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
  while locating play.api.db.DBApiProvider
  while locating play.api.db.DBApi
    for field at play.api.db.NamedDatabaseProvider.dbApi(DBModule.scala:80)
  while locating play.api.db.NamedDatabaseProvider
  at com.google.inject.util.Providers$GuicifiedProviderWithDependencies.initialize(Providers.java:149)
  at play.api.db.DBModule$$anonfun$namedDatabaseBindings$1.apply(DBModule.scala:34):
Binding(interface play.api.db.Database qualified with QualifierInstance(@play.db.NamedDatabase(value=default)) to ProviderTarget(play.api.db.NamedDatabaseProvider@14190249)) (via modules: com.google.inject.util.Modules$OverrideModule -> play.api.inject.guice.GuiceableModuleConversions$$anon$1)
Caused by: Configuration error: Configuration error[Cannot connect to database [default]]
```

Here is my application.conf file:

```
db.default.driver=com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
db.default.url="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/appdb"
db.default.username=root
db.default.password="root"
ebean.default = ["models.*"]
db.default.jndiName = DefaultDS

# JPA Configuration
jpa.default = defaultPersistenceUnit
```

I am using Gradle for building everything, and I added the needed dependencies (from build.gradle):

```
dependencies {
    play "org.hibernate:hibernate-entitymanager:4.3.10.Final"
    play "com.typesafe.play:play-java-jpa_2.11:2.4.2"
    play "com.typesafe.play:play-java-jdbc_2.11:2.4.3"
}
```

I can connect to the database (yes, I have appdb created) using MySQL Workbench without any problems and even have data inserted.

I already searched on multiple sources, but no luck. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

In case others are having the same problem, the correct import is not com.typesafe.play:play-java-jdbc_2.11:2.4.3
Use mysql:mysql-connector-java:5.1.36 and it will work.